# Create an ubuntu distribution that is an accurate copy of what is now in my HDD

Tags: system-installation

I was able to install Ubuntu on a mini pc and to configure everything I needed, I lost a lot of time configuring stuff and recompiling part of the kernel following different tutorials on internet. I have also customized unity, now I don't want to loose the same time next time.

Is there a way to create a distribution from what is now in my HDD and be sure that if I install this distro next time on the same machine,or another,  starting from scratch, everything will be exactly how it is now?

(I don't want to create a disk image.)

Comment: Makulu & other Ubuntu based distros have created scripts for their own use, that creates the ISO from an installed [Ubuntu] system. You could look for and use one of those.

Comment: Please don't. It is a waste of time. Even if you need to maintain 100+ identical systems there are better methods. I would advice to create a text file with "sed" and "apt install" commands so you can execute it post-install. Far more robust and easier to check for lines that need to be removed for future releases.

Comment: Make a backup or clone of your current system, you can restore it as you see fit and everything will be the same as it is now.

Comment: Clonezilla sounds like what you are looking for. You could create an identical image and then deploy that image on whichever machine you want.